# Firestore to automatically create a timestamp field with its own google time

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Does firestore have this feature where it will create a timestamp field with their own time when creating a new document... So it wont matter where ever the document has been created from, the time zone will be same for every country because i believe firebase has one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for Firestore's [server timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp). When you write a field with that value into a document, the Firestore server will expand it to the current time on the server.

If you want to prevent users from writing other values to this field, you can use Firebase's server-side security rules to enforce that the value of the field is equal to the [`request.time`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#time) built in variable.

Comment: it is not clear neither in your answer or in the docs you linked to how to get and read the server timestamp you mentioned for a doc

Comment: This question was about **writing** a timestamp, not reading it? Your use-case seems different, so did you consider posting a new question or searching further for an existing question that better covers your use-case? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @JohnMiller There is nothing special about reading a server timestamp field in a document.  It ends up exactly the same as reading any other timestamp type field. There is no record of it having originated as a server timestamp.

Comment: Why would anybody want to write a timestamp if they didn't intend to also read it? that doesn't make any sense to me. With that said, Separating the two into separate questions also doesn't make much sense to me. If you can write the timestamp, that only begs the question.